# how can I use Formik with react native element dropdown selector

Tags: javascript, react-native, formik, react-native-element-dropdown

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Text } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';




const MyForm = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

    const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
    // console.log(value)

    const data = [
        { label: 'A', value: '0' },
        { label: 'B', value: '1' },
        { label: 'C', value: '2' },
        { label: 'D', value: '3' },
   

    ]

    const renderLabel = () => {
        if (value || isFocus) {
            return (
                <Text style={[styles.label, isFocus && { color: 'blue' }]}>
                    Size
                </Text>

            );
        }

        return null;
    };
    return (
        <Formik

            initialValues={{ Size: '' }}
            onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        >

            {({ handleSubmit, handleChange}) => (
                <View style={styles.container}>

                    {renderLabel()}
                    <Dropdown
                        style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && { borderColor: 'blue' }]}
                        placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
                        selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
                        inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
                        iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
                        data={data}

                        search
                        maxHeight={300}
                        labelField="label"
                        valueField="value"
                        placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Size' : '...'}
                        searchPlaceholder="Search..."
                        value={value}
                        onChangeText={handleChange}  
                        onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
                        onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
                       onChange={item => {
                            setValue(item.value);
                            setIsFocus(false);

                        }}

                    />

                    <Button title="Submit" onPress={handleSubmit} />
                </View>
            )}
        </Formik>
    );
};

export default MyForm;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 16,
        margin: 10,
    },
    dropdown: {
        height: 50,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderRadius: 8,
        paddingHorizontal: 8,
    },
    icon: {
        marginRight: 5,
    },
    label: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        left: 22,
        top: 8,
        zIndex: 999,
        paddingHorizontal: 8,
        fontSize: 14,
    },
    placeholderStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    selectedTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    iconStyle: {
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
    },
    inputSearchStyle: {
        height: 40,
        fontSize: 16,
    },
});
```

I tried all in can think of help anyone
"dependencies": {
"expo": "~48.0.18",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
"formik": "^2.4.2",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "2.14.4",
"yup": "^1.2.0"
},

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community currently the problem is on submitting the form the values that the user selected do not appear............. it will appear like {Size: ''}    without selected values

Answer (score 0):

[image]in order to handle selected item by Dropdown you should use setFieldValue from Formik and change value to values.Size .For good experience add your shema validation to handle the Formik goal .
So imade some change to this component and it 's working like charm

```
   [![import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import {Input, Button} from '@rneui/themed';
import {Dropdown} from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
import {Formik, useFormikContext} from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
const Register = () => {

  const \[value, setValue\] = useState(null);

  const \[isFocus, setIsFocus\] = useState(false);
  // console.log(value)

  const data = \[
    {label: 'A', value: '0'},
    {label: 'B', value: '1'},
    {label: 'C', value: '2'},
    {label: 'D', value: '3'},
  \];

  const renderLabel = () => {
    if (value || isFocus) {
      return (
        <Text style={\[styles.label, isFocus && {color: 'blue'}\]}>Size</Text>
      );
    }

    return null;
  };
  const sizeValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    Size: yup.string().required('Size is required'),
  });
  return (
    <Formik
      validationSchema={sizeValidationSchema}
      initialValues={{Size: ''}}
      onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}>
      {({
        handleSubmit,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        setFieldValue,
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        isValid,
      }) => (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {renderLabel()}
          <Dropdown
            style={\[styles.dropdown, isFocus && {borderColor: 'blue'}\]}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
            data={data}
            // search
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Size' : '...'}
            searchPlaceholder="Search..."
            value={values.Size}
            onChangeText={handleChange('Size')}
            onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
            onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
            onChange={item => {
              setFieldValue('Size', item.value);
              setValue(item.value);
              setIsFocus(false);
            }}
          />
          {errors.Size && <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errors.Size}</Text>}
          <Button title="Submit" onPress={handleSubmit} />
        </View>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Register;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 16,
    margin: 40,
  },
  dropdown: {
    height: 50,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  label: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    left: 22,
    top: 8,
    zIndex: 999,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  placeholderStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  selectedTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  iconStyle: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
  inputSearchStyle: {
    height: 40,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  errorText: {
    fontSize: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'red',
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
});][1]][1]
```